# sort multiple files according to 2nd column decreasingly

Tags: shell, sorting

I need to sort all files whose names end with .txt decreasingly according to the second column (which is a number not a string). All the files have two integer columns, and I need the sorting to take effect on the same files.

For example, suppose file1.txt contains

```
1            33
2            55
3            22
```

and file2.txt contains

```
10            133
2             551
30            2200
```

I need a shell command that processes both *.txt files (in reality I have 100s of them) and affects them as follows:

file1.txt becomes:

```
2            55
1            33
3            22
```

file2.txt becomes:

```
30            2200
2             551
10            133
```

Comment: @jonathan-leffler Thanks, but (1) the order is increasing here and I need it decreasing and (2) I need the command to save the sorted data in the same files (i.e. overwrite old files). Is this possible?

Comment: `for file in *.txt; do sort -k2nr -o "$file" "$file"; done` sorts each file in reverse order, and overwrites (safely) the each separate original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments:

```
for file in *.txt; do sort -k2nr -o "$file" "$file"; done
```

The `-k2nr` sorts on field 2 in reverse numeric order.  The `-o` option followed by one of the input file names (here, the only input file name) safely overwrites the file with the sorted output.